# What is the name of TV show in 90 that some of the fighter pilots were born by In Vitro

Tags: story-identification, tv

I also remember that the flight team had name to do with deck of cards. Aces, spades or maybe duces?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is probably [Space: Above and Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%3a_Above_and_Beyond) which aired in the mid-90's.

The show focuses on the 58th Squadron of Space Aviator Cavalry - a group of Marines called "The Wildcards".

It also featured artificially gestated humans called "In Vitroes".

Answer (score 10):

It was [Space: Above and Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/).

The team's name was "Wildcards".